# Add grub2 entries in Ubuntu

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I had centOS installed in my system and after installing ubuntu the boot loader (grub2) doesn't display CentOS entry. I tried "sudo update-grub" in Ubuntu terminal but it doesn't show CentOS image. I also installed "grml-rescueboot" as mentioned in the grub2 manual but it also didn't work. How should I add CentOS manually in the grub2 of Ubuntu? I would be grateful if someone tells me how to fix this issue.

Comment: Reinstall grub with sudo grub-install /dev/sda, and follow that with sudo update-grub.

Comment: I tried to do so, but I got the error- "failed to get canonical path of /cow"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) is your tool unless you installed Ubuntu to the same partition and overwrote CentOS.

Comment: Boot repair worked wonders! Thank you so much for your suggestion :-D

Comment: It saved my life not once ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `grub.cfg` , the new entries will be added automatically. From the existing OS (Ubuntu) open the terminal and type the following command:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```